# How to tell if Sub is called from immediate window

Tags: vba, excel, immediate-window

Some subs I only ever want to run from the immediate window, like this slightly risky one:

```
Public Sub clear()

Application.SendKeys "^a", True
Application.SendKeys "{delete}", True

End Sub
```

In case you can't work it out; it sends <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> to the application, and has the effect of clearing whatever is around the cursor at the time.

I use it in the immediate window by typing `clear` and everything in the immediate window is removed.

As you can probably tell, this Sub is very dangerous and relatively simple to accidentally call. Therefore I would like to have it run *only* when called from the immediate window

- Not from another Sub
- Not from a Form Control
- Not from ActiveX (although that's effectively just a sub)
- Not from a user call (through the Developer/Macros tab)

And not from any other source either (I've listed all those, because I think even if you can't directly tell that it was called by the immediate window, you might be able to tell indirectly by ruling out the other options)

Is this possible to do programatically? Ideally, I just want to have a simple Boolean check at the start of my `clear()` sub, telling it to do nothing unless called by the immediate window.

---

#### *N.B.*

One route might be through the use of the *Call Stack* (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open the dialogue box), as I notice immediate calls leave no trace in the stack whereas subs calling `clear()` are listed and so can be ruled out. But I'm not sure how to access this through VBA

Comment: You say "*this Sub is very dangerous and relatively simple to accidentally call.*" so I would rename the function into e.g. `cleardebug` so it differs from anything like `listbox.clear()` and there is no more accidentally calling of it. Someone should not accidentally call a function called `cleardebug`, can't imagine a scenario where this would ever happen accidentally.

Comment: @Peh I agree that it might help with vba calls, but I'm not fully convinced for 2 reasons; First, that main form of accidental calling that I can think of is just clicking on the wrong macro in the run macros window - changing the name wouldn't solve this. Secondly, typing `cleardebug` feels like more effort than just doing ctrl+a+del manually (obviously you could pick a different name, but finding something obvious enough to be memorable but obscure enough not to have another meaning in VBA, and concise enough to type is hard)!

Comment: Ok let me say that there are about 1000 discussions, how-tos and tutorials out in the web on how to clear out the immediate window and about 10 different solutions to that issue. If there was a solution like detecting the immediate window as function caller (or like you suggested the other way round) I think someone would have found that already. I think there is no better solution to that beside these which the discussions already pointed out.

Comment: @Peh Valid point, *but* it's possible that a new question wording will attract some different ideas, I found no mention of this approach in the research I did (almost certainly because it is a fruitless approach, but possibly because it was not being considered)

Comment: I've always used the button provided on MZ Tools for clearing the Immediate Window - unfortunately not free any more.  https://www.mztools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one approach that combines some ideas:

```
Public Sub clear(Optional s As Variant)

If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Error" And IsMissing(s) = False Then
'Do code
End If

End Sub
```

What's going on is that if a sub is called from a range (functions only) or a button then this is caught by the `TypeName` test, as these will return `Range` and `String` respectively. Error options are immediate window, a Sub or a user call. The extra argument can't be given by a User, so that's ruled out. Finally, we hope a sub call won't contain the argument.

`s` is `Variant` so that you can type `clear whatever` in the immediate window, rather than having to put `watever` in `"` (to denote text).

Obviously can be made safer with a proper argument. Obviously it's not ideal as the word *hope* was meant to show! And of course it doesn't really answer the question either.

Comment: Small point: your argument is optional so doesn't have to be supplied **at all** when calling the routine, whether by the user (possible though unlikely) or by another sub.

Comment: @Rory,  but I check if it `IsMissing` making it necessary for the code within the sub to run, just not for the sub as a whole to run (to avoid errors when it is called accidentally)

Comment: Sorry - I overlooked that part. Technically the extra argument *can* be given by the user, it's just not going to happen accidentally! ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add a parameter

```
Public Sub clear(sCaller As String)

If sCaller = "Immediate" Then
    Application.SendKeys "^a", True
    Application.SendKeys "{delete}", True
End If

End Sub
```

This is possibly also not what you want but would clearly minimize the risk

Comment: In fact it could even be an optional parameter, because user/button clicks can't pass the string, and it would be hard to accidentally type in a sub. So having it `Optional` just avoids error messages but doesn't make it any less safe

Comment: Or you change your original code to Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the answer to your question, but if you want to "clear" your immediate window, this is what I use:

```
Sub clear()
For i = 0 To 100
    Debug.Print ""
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have seen this elsewhere, in the great [clear the immediate window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10203349/6609896) debate, I don't like how it leaves the cursor at the bottom of the window though. Also, as you say, it answers my specific case but not the actual question (although workarounds are in the SO spirit!).