# immediate window: clear before debug.print

Tags: vba, immediate-window

I would like to add a code to clear immediate window.

When programming I like to use debug.print.
To make the debug.print a bit more convenient, I wrote a small code below.
A problem occurs, when clearing the immediate window.
On my machine this code clears the immediate window, write all the debug.print entries an then clears it again.
I searched a lot codes and tried many of them without success.
I appreciate your answer - thanks!

```
Sub dp(Optional Identifier As String, Optional v As Variant, Optional ClearWindow As Boolean, Optional blnLineTop As Boolean, Optional blnLineEnd As Boolean)

'=================================================================================
'make debug.print more comfortable
'
'copy this:                             Call dp(Identifier ,v ,ClearWindow ,blnLineTop ,blnLineEnd)
'
'=================================================================================

'variables
Dim i           As Long
Dim sLine       As String: sLine = "--------------------------------------------"

'Pre
If ClearWindow Then
  With Application.VBE.Windows("Direktbereich")
    .Visible = True
    .SetFocus
    Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"
    Application.SendKeys ("{F7}")
  End With
End If

'Main
If Identifier = "" And IsEmpty(v) = Empty And ClearWindow = False And blnLineTop = False And blnLineEnd = False Then
  Debug.Print
Else

  Select Case Identifier
  Case Is <> vbNullString
    If blnLineTop Then Debug.Print sLine
  
    If IsArray(v) Then
      For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        Debug.Print Identifier & " (" & (i) & ")", " : ", CStr(v(i))
      Next
    Else
      Debug.Print Identifier, " : ", CStr(v)
    End If
    
    If blnLineEnd Then Debug.Print sLine
  Case Is = vbNullString
    If blnLineTop Then Debug.Print sLine
    If blnLineEnd Then Debug.Print sLine
  End Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Previous discussion on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203349/use-vba-to-clear-immediate-window